# Firebase registration error in iOS by react native

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to figure an error out with Firebase, bit it didn't work well.
Is there anyone to help me?

What I'm doing is :

1. building iOS app by react-native library
2. attaching Firebase on this native app

and it worked well in the first place until I CHANGED bundle identifier of my iOS app.

What I did is :

- changed bundle identifier on info.plist
- renamed folder structure
- renamed scheme
- renamed project and workspace name

and it turns out that everything works fine except the execution app on simulator.. :(

After **succeeding** build, when I try to execute app on simulator, error message comes out like the following :

> 7.1.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100005] FIRInstallations error: Error Domain=com.firebase.installations Code=0 "Underlying error: 작업을 완료할 수 없습니다. SecItemCopyMatching (-34018)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Underlying error: 작업을 완료할 수 없습니다. SecItemCopyMatching (-34018), NSUnderlyingError=0x6000018be0a0 {Error Domain=com.gul.keychain.ErrorDomain Code=0 "SecItemCopyMatching (-34018)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=SecItemCopyMatching (-34018)}}}

> 7.1.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF710001] Unable to fetch configurations.

where the meaning of Korean word in the error message is "CANNOT FINISH THE JOB."

it says "firebase installations error occurs." because it cannot fetch configurations.

What should I do to get rid of this error? please help.. I'm struggling with this about a week.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the `GoogleServices-info.plist` yourself.

If you changed the bundle ID for your app, define a new app in your Firebase project, download the updated `plist` and use that to replace the previous one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already did. I changed plist file, cleaned the whole project, rebuilt. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. After I changed Firebase config file, `GoogleServices-info.plist`, What should I do is CLEAN ALL THE PROJECT.

Even cleaning build in Xcode, deintegrating pod file, reset yarn node_modules folder, they're not enough.

What I did is :
`npx react-native-clean-project` and cleaned all the options.

then the error is gone.